# how can I access active element value

Tags: javascript

I try to get active element id(element now focus) but it does not return any value but when I write the code direct in console it return the active element id

```
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(){
console.log(document.activeElement.id);
}
```

this code done

```
document.activeElement.onclick = function(){
console.log(document.activeElement.id);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the active element? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Well what would the active element be? what you clicked, the button? If it is to be the element that was active before the click, then click is the wrong event.

Comment: when you click the button the focused element is no more the input you want.

Comment: Clicking the button takes the focus away from whatever element had it up to that point, so now the button has the focus.

Comment: What changes? Please update your question so that someone else with the same issue can be helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click event will have the button as the active element. If you need what is active before the button is clicked, then you need to listen for the mousedown which fires before the focus is lost.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
  console.log("mousedown", document.activeElement.id);
})

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log("click", document.activeElement.id);
})

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
  console.log("mouseup", document.activeElement.id);
})
```

```html
<a href="#" id="a1">a1</a>
<a href="#" id="a2">a2</a>
<button id="TheButton">Test</button>
<a href="#" id="a3">a3</a>
<a href="#" id="a4">a4</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to work with the element you clicked on in the callback, use `this`.

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript event.target get event target element

```
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(e)

  console.log(e.target.id);
}
```

If you want active element for example focus element

```
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(){
console.log(document.activeElement.id);
}
```